# Running on load chrome extension error ( document undefined )

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need your help :)

I'd like to build an chrome extension running everytime the tab load to add a button according to the type of gmail page that is open.

When the page load I have the error below : Error in event handler: ReferenceError: document is not defined at injectedFunction. When I add the injectedFunction code on to a dedicated content-script-file document is not recognize for the appendchild.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Don't use a background script. Instead declare a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in manifest.json: it will run directly in the page, so you won't need to inject anything further.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. It seems that the content-script.js is not launching. Here is my manifest, am I right ?

Comment: manifest.json : {
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "author": "JV",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "name": "Phishing Alert",
  "description": "Add a button to Gmail to declare phishing",
  "action": {"default_title": "Click to show an alert"},
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "tabs", 
    "declarativeContent"],
  "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/*"],
     "run_at": "document_end",
     "js": ["content-script.js"]
   }
 ]
}

Comment: content-script.js : var button = document.createElement("button")
button.innerText = "Declare phishing"
button['id'] = 'inserted'
button['data-name'] = 'name1'
button['class'] = 'ams bkG'
button['style'] = 'cursor:pointer;background-color: white;color: #ff0000;border: 1px solid #ff0000;border-radius: 5px;height: 120%;'
button.onclick = function() {

window.open(
            "myformurl", "_blank");
}
document.getElementsByClassName("amn")[0].appendChild(button);

Comment: GMail is a modern SPA site so you need to run the content script on the entire site `"matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"]` and wait for the appropriate time by using MutationObserver listener, where you'll check for location.href or for an existence of a certain element if that's more convenient.